# Bootstrap active tab gap bottom in Firefox

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I using the bootstrap tabs justified and, only in Firefox, there is a gap under the active tab:

[screenshot of the bug](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9kSkX.png)

This is not a margin nor a padding and I can't get rid of that.

Here is the custom code for the navtabs, other than that it is the default bootstrap style:

```
.nav-tabs li {
  border-radius: 5px 5px;

  a{
    background-color: #bebebe;
    color: black;
  }
}

.nav-tabs > li.active > a {
  background-color: white !important;
  border-bottom: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.nav-tabs > li > a:hover, .nav-tabs > li > a:active, .nav-tabs > li > a:focus{
  background-color: white !important;
  border-bottom: hidden;
}
```

EDIT:

Here is the html, it is a Laravel5 project by the way.

```
<div class="results">
<ul class="nav nav-tabs nav-justified" role="tablist">
    <li role="presentation" class="active"><a href="#user" aria-controls="user" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Users</a></li>
    <li role="presentation"><a href="#post" aria-controls="post" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Posts</a></li>
</ul>
<div class="tab-content">
    <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane fade in active" id="user">
    Content User….
     </div>
    <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane fade" id="post">
        Content Post
     </div>
</div>
```

Comment: 1. post your `html` code as well and 2. have you tried removing the `border-bottom` rules?

Comment: do u have it in jsfiddle?

Comment: I edited my post with the html. I already tried to remove border-bottom rules but it doesn't work, it only makes the gap slightly bigger since it adds the border I removed.

Comment: Here is the jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/1tbvqmkw/3/